# How can I know if my Neural Network is doing good or not using Mean_Square_Error (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm using Keras and I'm trying to build a Neural Network to predict the interest rate of given data. The data looks like this:

```
    loan_amnt   annual_inc  emp_length  int_rate
    10000    38000.0         5.600882          12.40
    13750    17808.0         5.600882          28.80
    26100    68000.0         10.000000         20.00
    13000    30000.0         1.000000          20.00
    7000     79950.0         7.000000          7.02
```

The features (X) are `loan_amnt` , `annual_inc` , and `emp_length`. The target (y) is `int_rate`.

Here's my process and what I've done after normalizing the data:

```
      #Building out model
     model = Sequential([
     Dense(9, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,)),
     Dense(3, activation='relu'),
     Dense(1, activation='linear'),
     ])

      #Compiling model
      model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error',
              metrics=['mse'],
              optimizer='RMSprop')

       hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=100, epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

Here's an output sample after running `model.fit()`:

```
    Epoch 1/20
    693/693 [==============================] - 1s 905us/step - loss: 96.2391 - mean_squared_error: 
    179.8007
    Epoch 2/20
    693/693 [==============================] - 0s 21us/step - loss: 95.2362 - mean_squared_error: 
    176.9865
    Epoch 3/20
    693/693 [==============================] - 0s 20us/step - loss: 94.4133 - mean_squared_error: 
    174.6367
```

Finally, evaluating the model `model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train)` and got the following output:

```
      693/693 [==============================] - 0s 372us/step
      [77.88501817667468, 132.0109032635049]
```

The question is, how can I know if my model is doing well or not, and how can I read the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a variant of the `MSE` loss which is defined as :

`MSE = mean((y_true - y_pred)^2)`

So when you have `132.` as a MSE metrics,  then you really have a mean of `sqrt(132.)`~= 11,5 mean difference between the y_true and y_pred. Which is quite a bit on your data as it is shown on the `MSPE` loss, you're having ~78% error on your data.

In example if the y_true was 20, you could either predict 36 or 4. Something like that.

You could say that your error is good when MSPE is at 10%. Depends on your case

Comment: So you're saying I should save the model as pickle and then test the model to evaluate my results? Also, you think the mse is not that good right?

Comment: I'm saying that your model is not performing well. Mse is perfectly fine and is the good way, either you need to change the model (may be too little, you should look at the litterature) or add more data. And yes as Nathan said, you need to evaluate your data on other than the training set. To do so you don't need to save your model, you will do that once your model is fine and you only want to predict using it. You need to have another subset(X_val, y_val) not correlated to the (X_train, y_train) subset and evaluate on it

Comment: Take a look at : [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/)

Answer (score 1):

You should not check the accuracy of your model using the training data because it makes your solution prone to overfitting. Instead you should set some data aside (20% is what I usually use) to validate your results.

If you plan on doing a lot of testing you should set aside a third dataset only for testing the final solution.

You can also use k_folds cross validation where you train the set on part of the data and use the rest to evaluate it, but doing so multiple times to get a better understanding of how accurate your model is.

Comment: What about the loss, is it the higher the worse?

Comment: MSE is Mean Standard Error, a larger MSE is a larger error is worse, yes